# The chat client-server multithread doesn't work

Tags: java, server, client, client-server, chat

image of a error:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBqO9.png)

i am creating a multi threaded client server chat with 2 clients. The program gives no errors, but the message I send does not reach the client, how can I do it? writing
hello # client 1
the message should get to the second client but it doesn't.
how do i change the client name?
Below I leave the files respectively of the server and the client that I wrote:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.net.*;



public class Server{


static Vector<ClientHandler> lc = new Vector<>();

static int i = 0; 

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2104);

    while (true){

        Socket s = ss.accept(); 
        System.out.println("Ricevuta nuova richiesta del client " + s);

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(s,"Client numero" + i, dis, dos);

        Thread t = new Thread(ch); 
          
        System.out.println("Il client si sta aggiungendo alla lista");

        lc.add(ch);

        t.start();

        i++;
    } 
} 
} 







class ClientHandler implements Runnable{ 
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
private String name; 
final DataInputStream dis; 
final DataOutputStream dos; 
Socket s; 
boolean login; 
  

public ClientHandler(Socket s, String name, DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos){ 
    this.dis = dis; 
    this.dos = dos; 
    this.name = name; 
    this.s = s; 
    this.login=true; 
}


@Override
public void run(){
    String ricevuta; 
    while (true){
        try{ 

            ricevuta = dis.readUTF(); 

            System.out.println(ricevuta); 

            if(ricevuta.equals("logout")){ 
                this.login=false; 
                this.s.close(); 
                break; 
            } 
            

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ricevuta, "#"); 
            String MsgToSend = st.nextToken(); 
            String recipient = st.nextToken(); 


            for (ClientHandler mc : Server.lc){ 

                if (mc.name.equals(recipient) && mc.login==true){ 
                    mc.dos.writeUTF(this.name+ " : " +MsgToSend); 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
        } catch (IOException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    } 
    try{ 

        this.dis.close(); 
        this.dos.close(); 
          
    }catch(IOException e){ 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 
}






import java.io.*; 

import java.net.*; 

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {
final static int ServerPort = 2104; 
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{ 


Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost"); 
      

    Socket s = new Socket(ip, ServerPort); 
      

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 

    
    
    

    Thread sendMessage = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
        @Override
        public void run(){ 
            while (true){

                String messaggio = scn.nextLine();
                try { 

                    dos.writeUTF(messaggio); 
                } catch (IOException e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
      
    
    
    

    Thread readMessage = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (true){ 
                try { 

                    String messaggio = dis.readUTF(); 
                    System.out.println(messaggio); 
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }); 


    sendMessage.start(); 
    readMessage.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the error to the question by pasting it as text.

Comment: i found the error, basically i was not writing the output correctly with the recipient. however, the message is not sent anyway.
writing:
hello # client 1
in the first client it should send it to the second one but it doesn't

Comment: however the error is in the link image

Comment: There are many reasons that the rules state text is necessary. For one thing, I can't read images of text. Second, can you guarantee that the image will remain up as long as this question? Third, will anybody be able to search on the image of the text as easily as they could the text?

Comment: I can't put the image normally but only through links because the site doesn't let me put it
2 the error is not in the image, but anyway now I add it again
3 I understand the problem that is in the image but now I don't know how to send the message, I changed the whole problem at the beginning of the question

Comment: But you could have easily copied the text from you IDE and then pasted the error as text into the question. We expect as much effort from you as you hope to receive from the people who answer your question.

Comment: I'm sorry for having made a mistake in inserting the image, the moment I thought about transcribing my problem I didn't think about copying and pasting it here. In any case, to see the image just click on the link called "image".
In any case, even if I wanted to send the error text, I can no longer do it because it does not reappear again and I have already written several times that the problem is no longer that but, indeed, send the message to the second client.